# Place View under another View within ConstraintLayout

Tags: java, android, android-constraintlayout

How do I place `View` behind another `View` in `ConstraintLayout`? Basically I want to achieve this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<View
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/view2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</FrameLayout>
```

When view1 is behind view2 in the Z axis.

Answer (score 5):

This code will put a view below another view.

Use constraints to constrain the views to the bottom and top.
If you want the view to take up the entire space, use  layout_height="0dp" and  layout_constraintHeight_default="spread".

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#F0F000"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="spread"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"></LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:background="#FF00FF"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"></LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: enter code here]

Answer (score 2):

Simply try

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="VIEW 1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="VIEW 2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/view1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/view1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/view1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/view1"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

To direct children of a `ConstraintLayout` you may use a great deal of `app:layout_constraint...` attributes to achieve the optimal layout you are looking for.

All 4 of those `layout_constraint` are not necessary any one of them will do the trick. But just to show you your options.

Comment: Adding `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view1"` will create constraint between the top and bottom of the views and won't place them one above each other. This is not what I was trying to achieve

Comment: When you say place them one above the other, do you mean you want view1 to be vertically above view 2, or literally above as in they are overlapping? @ben

Comment: I see that perhaps you wanted them to be overlapping one another I will update the code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Same as frame layout actually.
Lets take a look together:[image]

Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="TextView1" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="TextView2" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

If you want to see textView1 on the top of the screen, you should put the latest in the xml. Like:
[image]
Above image has this xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="TextView2" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="TextView1" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

As you can see only the order is changed. I hope this will help.